# VC++ doesn't append dimension on T[N] expression

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, visual-c++

I've written small utility to generate array of type T with specified dimensions. I know this sounds ridiculous, but lets ignore the usability and purpose for now:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t first, std::size_t ... rest>
struct generate_dimensions
{
    using type = typename generate_dimensions<T, rest...>::type[first];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t first>
struct generate_dimensions<T, first>
{
    using type = T[first];
};
```

(I know I need to remove all extents first, but please ignore it for now)

So, after using it:

```
generate_dimensions<int, 3, 4, 5>::type;
```

VC++ claims that type is `int[3]` (All released updates were installed). Whereas ideone C++14 compiler (gcc?) [gives right answer](http://ideone.com/xvOz97), e.g. `int[3][4][5]`.

My question is: which compiler is right? If either one, then why?

VC++ compiler version is 19.00.24210 for x86.

Comment: which version of visual-c++ do you use 'cause in 19.00.23720.0 (x86) ([webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)) your code work as a charm producing `int [3][4][5]`...

Comment: @W.F., Thanks, I will update the question

Comment: `19.00.23506 for x86` [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) also gives `int [3][4][5]`

Comment: my guess it's your version bug... :/

Comment: @W.F., probably so. I tried the rextester too and got right result. Is there a place where I can submit the bug ?

Comment: I think you can do it over [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback)